# Java: Collection to use to store 900,000 customer number

Tags: java, performance

For one of the use case I wanted to store approx 900,000 customer number to do shuffling. It will have 2 columns - one original customer num and the other shuffled customer num.

What is the best approach using Java, so that I don't get memory exception or GC overhead?

Thanks.

Comment: 900,000 numbers would be less than 10Mb, I think you'll be just fine as long as you're not running on a GameBoy.

Comment: Seriously, this is hardly something related to collections. If your data is going to exceed heap size, using *any* collection or data structure is going to give you the same thing... unless you are looking for special API that does compression and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not much to store 900k numbers if a number is only 4 bytes. If you exceed the heap you can also increase the heap size with [Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java).

If your data grows and you need much space, then you can use a off the heap datastructure like http://www.mapdb.org/. They provide an Implementation of the List or Set or Map interface but save some data to the disk instead of the heap.